# Overriding module class in prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to override a class from a module I installed. The class is located in the modules folder in `MyModule/lib/MyClass.php`
So what i did is create a copy of that class in `override/modules/MyModule/lib/MyClass.php` and it's declared like this:

```
    class MyClassOverride extends MyClass {
        // custom code
    }
```

I also deleted the class_index.php file.

And my changes are not applied so i really don't know what I am missing here. Is it even possible to do that ? I heard that in previous versions of prestashop you couldn't override a module class...

Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

It seems that it's possible to override a php class for a module if the class is in `MyModule/MyClass.php`, but it doesn't work if the class is in `MyModule/lib/MyClass.php`...